# Is it safe to move Windows C:/ partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, uefi, efi, pop-os

I was trying to install Pop OS 20.04 LTS, alongside my Windows 10 installation, but it says that the EFI partition, which is 260 MB currently, is too small and that Pop requires it to be atleast 500 MB.

I decided to use AOMEI partitioning assistant to resize the EFI partition from Windows, but it requires that I move the Windows C:/ and MSR partitions. Is it safe to do so? And if not, how else can I extend my EFI partition?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both UEFI itself and the Windows Boot Manager find the next partition by reading the GPT partition table; the boot process does not rely on the file or partition locations being fixed.

(The Windows Boot Manager does however expect the partition *numbers* to remain the same, so while moving and resizing partitions is safe, adding/deleting/swapping can cause problems unless it's done through Windows DiskMgmt.)

As far as I know, the "MSR" partition doesn't really do anything.

Comment: +1. FWIW I've seen VeraCrypt'ed systems stop booting after removing MSR. Also GParted, which is built into Pop_OS's installer, is pretty reliable for resizing and moving Windows partitions. Not 100% reliable though (nothing is) and backups are still a necessity.

Comment: Can recommend gparted for resizing and moving partitions around.